# unable to connect rapberry to pc through mosquitto

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, mosquitto

i'm trying to check if my raspberry is able to connect to my pc through mosquitto.
I opened a shell on my pc and i entered this line in the prompt in order to do the subscription:

```
mosquitto_sub -h raspberry pi -t test
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to connect (Lookup error.).
```

I tried to reinstall mosquitto both in the raspberry and pc but i get the same result.

Comment: Which machine do you install the `mosquitto` broker on? How did you start it? What are the IP addresses of all the machines involved? Please click `edit` under your question and fill in all the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `raspberry pi` is not a valid hostname as it contains a space.

You probably mean `raspberrypi.local` which is the default mDNS/Avahi/Bonjour hostname for a raspberry pi.

Otherwise if you know the IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.5) of the raspberry pi you can use the following:

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.5 -t test
```